# Hide shortcodes "code" when using the "editor" the same as wordpress do with "gallery"

Tags: plugin-development, jquery, shortcode, visual-editor

i have question, how to hide the "shortcode code" when using the "editor" the same as wordpress do with "gallery"?

my clients hate to see shortcodes as "code". And the truth, not only him, but a lot of people who use wordpress.

when the user on "editor mode" i dont want to show the "shortcode code". but show on hover,  icons "edit" or "delete". like wordpress do with "gallery".

the edit can show popup the same as we are using in all shortcode in the post/page.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Solution to render Shortcodes in Admin Editor](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/36568/solution-to-render-shortcodes-in-admin-editor)

Comment: You might find the [ShortCake](http://wptavern.com/shortcake-a-ui-for-wordpress-shortcodes) plugin interesting (I'm not an affiliate).