# Change appearance of shortcode text inside editor

Tags: shortcode, the-content

Is it possible to change appearance of shortcodes in editor or in whatever way make it more distinguishable from surrounding text?

For example if the content of a post is like this...

> Reference site about Lorem Ipsum, giving information on its origins,
>   as well as a random Lipsum generator.Reference site about Lorem Ipsum,
>   giving information on its origins, as well as a random Lipsum
>   generator.[shortcode]asfdasfd[/shortcode]Reference site about Lorem
>   Ipsum, giving information on its origins, as well as a random Lipsum
>   generator.Reference site about Lorem Ipsum, giving information on its
>   origins, as well as a random Lipsum generator.Reference site about
>   Lorem Ipsum, giving information on its origins, as well as a random
>   Lipsum generator.

... it would be nice if the shortcode inside is bold so it can easily be seen like this:

[image]

Comment: That would definitely be convenient and surely is possible with some regex/js . Here is a [similar question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/40687) and a plugin that lets you add [previews for the shortcodes](https://github.com/wp-shortcake/shortcake) although simply highlighting all as you suggested, like you would `<code>` or `<pre>` tags would definitely be simpiler.

Comment: I know this isn't helpful to you right now but keep an eye on [Shortcake](https://make.wordpress.org/core/features-as-plugins/) for integration into core soon... will make this long needed core feature a reality

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Solution to render Shortcodes in Admin Editor](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/36568/solution-to-render-shortcodes-in-admin-editor)

Comment: /OFF topic from me, @brianjohnhanna I have seen that plugin but that is a kind of preview (so how it will look on frontend) of the code. If I understand the question well the question of the OP is highlighting the `shortcode tag` and `content` inside that `shortcode` in the editor.

Comment: I once had to do something similar and used this
[chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/pearls-extension/mccffpojdcohdkefnbfhfdcklpcagdlc?hl=en).

Comment: https://wordpress.org/plugins/shortcode-ui/

Comment: Might be interesting to see if you can make a visual indication using Adding Custom Text Patterns in the WP 4.5 Visual Editor http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/226054/84219

Answer (score 12):

You can add a custom plugin, to WordPress and also the TinyMCE visual editor. The follow source is a example that simple works and add a string before and after all shortcode.

### Usage

The shortcode will find via regex, relevant if you need it for different shortcodes and different mark on this. The script add custom content to the shortcode, here `<b>FB-TEST` before and after the closing tag and the content. You can also use markup, css classes to create a visibility. Important is it, that you remove this content on save post, fired in the script on `PostProcess`. Here run the script and remove the custom content via the function `restoreShortcodes`.

But, currently is this simple, maybe not valid for each requirement. Maybe you should store the shortcode on init and restore with this stored variable.

### Screenshot

See the screenshot as example to understand the result.

[image]

### Source

The source need this directory structure to use it:

```
-- shortcode-replace
 |--php file
 |--assets
   |-- js
     |-- js file
```

At first a small php file, that include the source as plugin in the wp environment. Leave it in the main directory of the plugin `shortcode-replace`.

```
<?php # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

/**
 * Plugin Name:     Shortcode Replace
 * Plugin URI:      
 * Description:     
 * Version:         0.0.1
 * Text Domain:     
 * Domain Path:     /languages
 * License:         MIT
 * License URI:
 */

namespace FbShortcodeReplace;

if ( ! function_exists( 'add_action' ) ) {
    exit();
}

if ( ! is_admin() ) {
    return;
}

add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', __NAMESPACE__ . '\initialize' );
function initialize( $page ) {

    if ( 'post.php' === $page ) {
        add_filter( 'mce_external_plugins', __NAMESPACE__ . '\add_tinymce_plugin' );
    }
}

function add_tinymce_plugin( $plugins ) {

    if ( ! is_array( $plugins ) ) {
        $plugins = array();
    }

    $suffix = defined( 'SCRIPT_DEBUG' ) && SCRIPT_DEBUG ? '.dev' : '';
    $url     = plugins_url( '/assets/js/fb_shortcode_replace.js', __FILE__ );

    $plugins = array_merge( $plugins, array( 'fb_shortcode_replace' => $url ) );
    return $plugins;
}
```

This php file load a javascript as plugin in the visual editor. The plugin will load only on admin pages, only pages with string `post.php` - see `if ( 'post.php' === $page ) {`.

The follow source is the javascript file, named `fb_shortcode_replace.js`. Leave it in the directory `assets/js/`, inside the plugin directory of this plugin.

```
tinymce.PluginManager.add( 'fb_shortcode_replace', function( editor ) {

    var shortcode = /\[.+\]/g;
    var additional_before = '<b>FB-TEST';
    var additional_after = 'FB-TEST</b>';

    function ifShortcode( content ) {

        return content.search( /\[.+\]/ ) !== -1;
    }

    function replaceShortcodes( content ) {

        return content.replace( shortcode, function( match ) {
            return html( match );
        } );
    }

    function restoreShortcodes( content ) {

        content = content.replace( additional_before, '' );
        content = content.replace( additional_after, '' );
        return content;
    }

    function html( data ) {

        console.log( data );
        return additional_before + data + additional_after;
    }

    editor.on( 'BeforeSetContent', function( event ) {

        // No shortcodes in content, return.
        if ( ! ifShortcode( event.content ) ) {
            return;
        }

        event.content = replaceShortcodes( event.content );
    } );

    editor.on( 'PostProcess', function( event ) {

        if ( event.get ) {
            event.content = restoreShortcodes( event.content );
        }
    } );
} );
```

### Helpful

- The comments on your questions.
- https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.4.2/src/wp-includes/js/tinymce/plugins/wpgallery/plugin.js

### Additional hint

The plugin [Raph](https://github.com/Giuseppe-Mazzapica/Raph) convert shortcodes in html to view it and simplify to understand the result. Maybe it is also helpful in this context.